# C# Selenium Library Chrome Driver not reading webpage precisely

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, page-load-time

I am using selenium library and chrome driver in C# for extraction of data.
I have tried many solutions but the problem still exists.

1. Chrome driver doesn't explicitly wait until page loads completely
2. sometimes chrome driver read previous record values and write to an excel file.

Solutions that i have tried are:

```
private static void WaitUntilDocumentIsReady(TimeSpan timeout, ChromeDriver WebDriver)
        {
            var javaScriptExecutor = WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeout);

            // Check if document is ready
            Func<IWebDriver, bool> readyCondition = webDriver => (bool)javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return (document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0)");
            wait.Until(readyCondition);
        }
```

and second one is.

```
detailDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade your Chrome version? I've hearing the lasts Chrome versions have some compatibilitie problems with Selenium.

Comment: @StriterAlfa no. I am using latest version of google chrome.